# inner-html directives

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-template

How can I use `[router-link]` in `[inner-html]`

Here is the example :

```
    import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
    import {RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

    @Component({
        selector: 'index'
    })
    @View({
        template: `
            <div> Index Content </div>
            <div [inner-html]="test"></div>
        `,
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })

    export class Index {
        private test: String;

        constructor() {
            this.test = `<a [router-link]="['/aRoute', 'AComponent']">Test</a>`;
        }
    }
```

Here is the solution for Angular1 http://plnkr.co/edit/F91xvGHBASvqCGBJcEYY?p=preview

How can I do it in Angular2 ?

Comment: I don't think the compiler would be aware of that routerLink. Why don't you just pass directly the routerLink in your template?

Comment: i need to get html via ajax and i dont want any page loading by setting href attr to a tags. Is there any way to manipulate the template after the component initialized, --sorry-for-my-english :)

Comment: You can use `templateUrl` instead of `template` to get a dynamic angular page loaded into the app

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution.

DynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot solves that issue.

Here is the API:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

There is an article also: https://medium.com/tixdo-labs/angular-2-dynamic-component-loader-752c3235bf9#.qkxk36s98

Edit: DynamicComponentLoader is deprecated, here is another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/5022904